# I created a notification channel, but I am getting an error that "Channel does not exist" or "invalid channel" on Android 10

Tags: android

I have been serving a app since 1 year ago.

I did  **createNotificationChannel**, **setChannelId** and **startForeground** for the foreground service, and I use same channel id and name for two services.

It worked fine until February.

```
private var notificationBuilder: Notification.Builder? = null

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    var channel = notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(notificationChannelId)
    if (channel == null) {
        channel = NotificationChannel(notificationChannelId, notificationChannelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

    if (notificationBuilder == null || startForeground) {
        notificationBuilder = Notification.Builder(service, channel.id)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.my_icon)
                .setColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(service.resources, R.color.my_color, null))
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setContentText(notificationMessage)
                .setContentIntent(notiClickPendingIntent)
                .setChannelId(notificationChannelId)

        val notiBuilder = notificationBuilder ?: return
        service.startForeground(notificationID, notiBuilder.build())
    } else {
        // update notification
        val notiBuilder = notificationBuilder ?: return
        notiBuilder
                .setContentText(notificationMessage)
                .setChannelId(notificationChannelId)
        notificationManager.notify(notificationID, notiBuilder.build())
    }
}
```

Recently, even though I haven't modified the related code, bug reports have started to occur since March.

```
Bad notification for startForeground: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Channel does not exist

Bad notification for startForeground: java.lang.RuntimeException: invalid channel for service notification
```

These errors are overwhelmingly common in Android 10, and often occurs in Android 9.

And it happened a lot in Galaxy s10 series and Galaxy Note 10 series.

Does anyone know any relevant information?

p.s. I would really appreciate it if you could give me a better English expression!